# Cannot find Python 3.8.2 path on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have Windows 10 on my computer and when I use the cmd and check `python --version`, I get python 3.8.2. But when I try to find the path for it, I am unable to find it through searching on my PC in hidden files as well as through start menu. I don't seem to have a python 3.8 folder on my machine. Anybody have any ideas how to find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can open the python interpreter `sys.executable` will give you the path.

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python paths in Windows can get a little strange. I prefer to use the official packages from [python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/). And I use the "install for all users" option. Finally, I prefer to have my Python installs one level below C: drive, i.e. C:\Python37.

If you do not use the "install for all users" option, the Python directory gets buried in C:\Users\xxx\xxx somewhere. And some IDEs (I'm looking at you PyCharm) like to install everything in virtual environments (venv).

@moeen.n answer of `sys.executable` is probably the easiest to find out where your install is.

Comment: In case anyone is reading this and wondering what the \xxx\xxx is, this is what I have: `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe`. As you said, this is where it goes if you install it just for your user, which is a useful option if you don't have the admin privileges to install for all users.

Comment: On the virtual environments thing, these are generally very useful and highly recommended, and I do say that as someone who took a little while to take the plunge, even after reading lots of people saying comments exactly like what I'm typing! It just seemed like a strange, arcane thing which I didn't understand. But in terms of this question, it's worth noting you still need Python to be installed somewhere else locally first to be able to create a virtual environment (and I *think* it needs to stay in place because the venv does "symbolic linking" so relies on the original file).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using cmd (ie Command Prompt), and typing `python` works, then you can get the path for it by doing `where python`. It will list all the pythons it finds, but the first one is what it'll be using.

Comment: Good one. I didn't know Windoze had `where`.

Comment: @bfris not that I've ever used Linux, but I learned `where` after someone told me about `which` on Linux... with the consequence that I can never remember which one is the Windows command. Also, if you're using PowerShell it's different again: `(Get-Command python).Path`  https://superuser.com/questions/34492/powershell-equivalent-to-the-unix-which-command

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy hack, after the default install if you again run the installer and select `Modify`, then proceed further and you will get an option to `Add Python to environment variables`.
[image]